# How to define a preprocessor macro that is used by a library?

Tags: c-preprocessor, arduino-esp8266

I am subclassing HardwareSerial and I want the application code to use my class instead of HardwareSerial. To facilitate this, I would like the Serial object to be an instance of my class rather than an instance of HardwareSerial.

Examining the HardwareSerial sources, it looks like it should be possible to prevent the Serial object from being created by defining either NO_GLOBAL_INSTANCES or NO_GLOBAL_SERIAL. I just can't figure out how to do that in such a way that it affects the compilation of the included HardwareSerial library, without modifying the HardwareSerial sources.

I expected to find a possibility to add preprocessor macros via a menu of the arduino ide somewhere. I also searched the web to see if there is a special header file that I could add to my project that gets included when compiling libraries. But neither of these options seem to be available. At least, I couldn't find them.

I initially resigned myself to just using a different name for the instance of my class and tell the application developers to use that. But that hit a snag with serialEventRun(), which is hardcoded to call Serial.available(). I need it to call the available method of the instance of my class.

So, it seems to me that all of this mess could be solved by passing the NO_GLOBAL_SERIAL definition to the preprocessor. The question is, how?

Comment: You seem to misunderstand. The macros are not for the library to change compilation, it's for the users of these library to conditionally include external symbols. The library stays.

Comment: @KamilCuk Can you elaborate? Who would be considered users of these libraries, if I don't qualify? And how would such users go about including external symbols?

Comment: I don't know how to do it in Arduino IDE. It should be easy with platformIO in the ini file, though.